# How to work with Firebase Asynchronously? Database reading giving odd results

Tags: swift, firebase, asynchronous, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have written the following function to search through my Firebase database and I have also looked into using debug statements and tested with breakpoints to see this function is pulling the correct data and it is. But when I return the array at the end, the array is empty. As far as I understand this is due to the asynchronous nature of firebase. The function is getting to the end before the data is being added to the array. How do I fix this so it can work as intended, I want to return an array of items which I can then use for other functions.

```
static func SearchPostsByTags(tags: [String]) -> [Post]{
    var result = [Post]()

    let dbref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")

    dbref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
        let comps = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]

        for(_, value) in comps {
            let rawTags = value["tags"] as? NSArray

            let compTags = rawTags as? [String]

            if compTags != nil {

                for cTag in compTags! {
                    for tag in tags {
                        if (tag == cTag) {
                            let foundPost = Post()
                            foundPost.postID = value["postID"] as! String
                            foundPost.title = value["title"] as! String

                            result.append(foundPost)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    return result
}
```

}

Comment: Search for completion handler/callback  in swift, I think this will solve your problem

Comment: You cannot achieve what you are trying to do. The best way to do it would be two methods. Get and Set and the get method will have a `completionHandler` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning your `array` before the `async` call ends. You should fill your array inside the async call and call then another method, which provides the results.

```
static func SearchPostsByTags(tags: [String]) {
    let dbref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts")
    dbref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
        let comps = snap.value as! [String : AnyObject]
        var result = [Post]()
        for(_, value) in comps {
            let rawTags = value["tags"] as? NSArray

            let compTags = rawTags as? [String]

            if compTags != nil {

                for cTag in compTags! {
                    for tag in tags {
                        if (tag == cTag) {
                            let foundPost = Post()
                            foundPost.postID = value["postID"] as! String
                            foundPost.title = value["title"] as! String

                            result.append(foundPost)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
       // Call some func to deliver the finished result array
       // You can also work with completion handlers - if you want to try have a look at callbacks / completion handler section of apples documentation
       provideTheFinishedArr(result)
    })
}
```

Comment: How would this prvideTheFinishedArr function look because wouldn't that just end up also completing before the database query if it just consists of

provideTheFinishedArr(result) {
    return result
}

Also how would i call SearchPostsByTags in order to return something